# How to add new external column to .XLSX file destination?

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, vb.net, ssis

I'm creating a package to load an .XLSX file in a SQL Server destination table. After using a lookup with referential table; I used derived column to put  the name  of the unmatched column in a reject table, It's all fine till now.

After this, I need to used again the same source file but this time as a destination, and add to it a new column at the end of existing columns, where I will put the column nam that I stored in my reject table and which doesn't match.

My issue, is that when I go to Advanced Editor for Excel Destination => Input and Output Properties => External Columns => Add Column. When I add a new column and go back to Column Mappings I do the mapping but after validation the new column desapears.

I use a variable sheet name and I've tried to use a SQL command and even when I select more columns A1:AC1 (I have columns in range A1:AB1), I don't get extra column available.

Comment: Did you try delay validation?

Comment: Welcome to the (awful) ACE drivers. Unfortunately you can't do what you're trying to do the way you are (that made sense, right?). You'll need to have the column defined already in your Excel file, and then you'll see it in your source and destinations (obviously you can ignore the column in your source). The ACE drivers are kind/stupid enough to ignore columns that have never been defined/used as they seem to see them as beyond the end of the file. If you can't add the header (with empty data) in the file, then you'll likely have to use a Script Component.

Comment: To add a little bit of additional info. What your experiencing is the same as when you amend the data types in your Source when using the ACE drivers. Regardless of what you **know** the ACE drivers will always choose the datatype "appropriate" for that column by sampling the first *x* number of rows (*x* is defined in a registry key). If you have a value after that many rows that doesn't conform to the expected data type, you'll get a conversion error. I've had several files that start off with number on values (so ACE treats is an an `int`) for there to be Alpha later; so the process fails..

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks for your answer. Actually I use the same Excel connection for source and destination and the Delayvalidation property is True.

Comment: @Larnu I'm very thankful for this precious information. If there is no way to change the ACE drivers properties; how can I add the header (with empty data) in the file ? I think that in this way it wont be possible if the header title will be empty...?(obvious) because  I can't ask my final user to add a new column each time he sends the file... It will be possible if I can do it only the first time to setup my package, but I'm not sure that SSIS will keep use this description for all the coming files, what do you think ?

Comment: @Larnu I didn't try using a script task because I thought that there is another way to do it (as the derived column exists) by adding a new column to destination. And what is strange to me is that in advanced editor, in input output columns we have the possibility to add external columns but I don't understand why it doesn't work however it exists ?

Comment: One possible workaround would be to create a new .xlsx for your destination, and once you finish your ETL process, delete the old file, and then rename the new one using the old file's filename.

Comment: @digital.aaron Thank you for your proposal, but after trying it it will not be possible in this situation I use the same file in output, in other words I have to keep the same structure of the file (same existing sheets) and the file will be used again by the user for corrections.